# AWS EC2 instance created from AMI don't works (Error 504) - WEBb don't run

Tags: mysql, wordpress, nginx, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I'm new on AWS but I read a lot of documentation to create, launch and image instances. Now I have a client that use AWS and have 2 instances EC2 runing commercial web sites (using Nginx and MySQL in Amazon RDS and Wordpress).

I need to create clones of this websites to have a Q.A. ambient. I try creating images from these instances and launching new instances with this, but this don't work. When I Try to visit the website clone using the IP of the instance, that shows a 504 error. (The idea is to have two instances ready to use with the same website. One for visitors use and another to do testes, updates, changes or to use when the another instance crash)

The on-air website domain is ibser.org, and the new instance domain (runing now) is [link to instance](http://ec2-18-207-188-172.compute-1.amazonaws.com)

Somebody may give me info that what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

@Wilmar Sometimes it do happen as you have created the image successfully but due to manual setup you have to start the services inside the Instance manually.

As per the link provided, its showing 504 Gateway time out, so please check with the Security group of your newly created Instance and sometimes A corrupt WordPress database may also trigger a 504 gateway timeout error. This means may be your mysql service is not running.

So my suggestion is SHH into your New instances and check with all the required services which all need to be in running state and do check with the database.